# What is the reason for the NullPointerException error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am writing a drowing app. At the moment i have the next issue, i get the next error when i am clicking on "redBtn" in "R.layout.activity_colors_prefs".

```
   08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.example.drawview.ChooseColor$1.onClick(ChooseColor.java:43)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

According to debug mode the problem is in this command:

- view_a.setdrawColor(Color.RED);

In the next class

```
public class ChooseColor extends Activity  {
    //View
    private DrawingView view_a;

    //Button
    Button redBtn;
    public int colorPref= Color.BLACK;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colors_prefs);
        redBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redColr);
        redBtn.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener);
        view_a=(DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    }

    public int getColorPref() {
        return colorPref;
    }


    private OnClickListener myButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.redColr:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view_a.setdrawColor(Color.RED);     
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    };

The method "setdrawColor" is the next:

public void setdrawColor(int color) 
{ 
   //create a copy of bitmap before changing the paint color 
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap); 
     canvas.setBitmap(bitmap); 
     paint.setColor(color); 
}
```

"setdrawColor" locatd in other activity, activity which called "DrawingView".
"DrawingView" resposnible for drawing and extends View and doesnt extends Activity.

Can you please edvice what is the problem? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's in line number 43( ChooseColor.java)?

Comment: Why view_a is null? Is your layout xml well defined? Is drawingView defined in your activity_colors_prefs layout?

Comment: Double click the line in the logcat that reads "08-26 03:27:31.576: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.example.drawview.ChooseColor$1.onClick(ChooseColor.java:43)"

It will take you to the line containing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this before you call the method and report the result

```
if (view_a != null) {
  view_a.setdrawColor(Color.RED);
} else {
  Log.e("ChooseColor","view_a is null!");
}
```

I'm thinking view_a is never properly set. Can you confirm this?

Comment: This, or R.layout.activity_colors_prefs is the wrong xml file and the widget is never being initialized, but you can make the call to findViewById(...)

Comment: No it is in onCreate:   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colors_prefs);
        redBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redColr);
        redBtn.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener);
        view_a=(DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    }